# Why does HAProxy show that a server's check URL is a 404 when running curl on this URL is successful?

Tags: haproxy

I'm setting up HAProxy to load-balance a resource between 3 back-ends. Here is the HAProxy config : (In the following snippets I replaced the actual domain name by example.net)

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local2
  log-send-hostname
  maxconn 2000
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
  stats timeout 30s
  daemon

   # SSL ciphers
  ...

defaults
  mode    http
  option  forwardfor
  option  contstats
  option  http-server-close
  option  log-health-checks
  option  redispatch
  timeout connect  5000
  timeout client  10000
  timeout server  10000
  ...

frontend front
  bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/front.pem
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
  stats uri /haproxy?stats
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  default_backend back
  balance source

backend back
  balance roundrobin
  option httpchk GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.0
  server server1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 check inter 5s fall 2 rise 1
  server server2 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:8003 check backup
  server mysite  example.net:80 check backup
```

The issue is the following: even though the first 2 servers respond correctly, the domain-based one always shows as a 404:

[image: HAProxy stats]

What is counter-intuitive to me is that if I use curl to access this same healthcheck, I get an HTTP 200 (like I would expect to see in the HAProxy stats) :

```
curl -I http://example.net/healthcheck
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

When I ping my site, I get:

```
# ping example.net
PING example.net (217.160.0.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 217-160-0-195.elastic-ssl.ui-r.com (217.160.0.195): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=45.7 ms
```

Is it because the IP of my domain is shared with other domains (1&1 shared hosting) that HAProxy can't access it? Why is that and how to make HAProxy reach it correctly?